# Azure Credit Vs Company Account

Tags: azure

I have Azure Account through the employer, and today added $50 Credit to the same account.
While using resources, will Azure bill through company or my personal credit ? How and where can i see it ? 
Already check cost management/billing and do not see anything due to insufficient privileges.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i think your credit is for a different subscription.

Comment: Thanks. It showed up in sometime as two different subscriptions on Azure. All is good!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your credit is for a different subsription; most likely - Visual Studio Professional.

Your company might have different permission for viewing costs; therefore, you are not able to see it.

I would recommend disabling or deleting resources in your subscription to keep the costs low.